# Custom Queries in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am very new to using Access and databasing in general. I need to set up a database to manage car loans. I currently have the following:

- A form which displays the information each individual customer
- A button at the bottom of the form, titled "View Customer History"
- A table with the records of all loans, sorted by car registration number

What I need to do is have access create a custom query which will display all the items from the table containing the loan records that have been rented by the customer that is being displayed in the form. I am aware that creating queries manually is an option but seems impractical due to the number of new customers loaning cars all the time.

I hope that the question made sense and appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have a look at subforms and subform controls with particular reference to Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would approach the task in this way:

1. Create two tables called "Customers" and "Loans"
2. "Customers" table should have unique records for each customer. One of the fields  in this table will be titled "Name" and should obviously contain the names of the customers. Make this field the Primary Key. The other fields will contain other information related to the customer
3. "Loans" table will have a field called "Customer" which stores the names of the customer loaning out the car. Link this field to the Primary Key of the "Customers" table. The other fields will contain details relating to the loan
4. Now your form (name of form: "Information") is linked to the "Customers" table and shows all the information stored in the table. Name the field on the form containing the name of the customer as "CustomerName". At the bottom of the form you have a button for viewing customer history
5. Create the query: SELECT * FROM Loans WHERE Loans.[Customer] = Forms!Information!CustomerName;
6. Assign this query to the 'On Click' event of the button on the form

There are of course other ways of achieving the desired results, but the way described above is also sufficient.

Comment: The downvote is because you have failed to mention subform controls, so this is not an optimal solution.